# markerClusterer on click zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I just added a MarkerClusterer to my google map. It works perfectly fine.

I am just wondering if there is any way of adjusting the zoom-in behaviour when the cluster is clicked. I would like to change the zoom level if possible.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I modified the clusterclick event as suggested:

```
/**
* Triggers the clusterclick event and zoom's if the option is set.
*/
ClusterIcon.prototype.triggerClusterClick = function() {
var markerClusterer = this.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer();

// Trigger the clusterclick event.
google.maps.event.trigger(markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', this.cluster_);

if (markerClusterer.isZoomOnClick()) {
// Zoom into the cluster.
// this.map_.fitBounds(this.cluster_.getBounds());

// modified zoom in function
this.map_.setZoom(markerClusterer.getMaxZoom()+1);

 }
};
```

It works great! Thanks a lot

Comment: What's differences between above codes and original ones?

Comment: @Kabkee the difference is this actually changes zoom and the code above is a skeleton.

Answer (score 62):

There has been an update to the MarkerClusterer source code, allowing much easier access to the click event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    // your code here
});
```

where 'markerCluster' ist the MarkerCluster object.
Inside the function you may also access

```
cluster.getCenter();
cluster.getMarkers();
cluster.getSize();
```

I use this to switch to a different map type, as I use a custom tile set for easier overview on lower zoom levels:

```
map.setCenter(cluster.getCenter()); // zoom to the cluster center
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP); // switch map type
map.setOptions(myMapOptions); // apply some other map options (optional)
```

Regards
Jack

Comment: Is this documented somehwhere?

Comment: It's documented here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

Comment: Works great ! Just don't forget to set the MarkerClusterer option zoomOnClick to false

Comment: @ApolloData: That link now throws a 404 error.

Comment: Documentation now is here:

https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/

Answer (score 13):

You can do this without modifying the source code by using a listener on the clusterclick markerClusterer event:

```
var mcOptions = {gridSize: 40, maxZoom: 16, zoomOnClick: false, minimumClusterSize: 2};
markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function(cluster){
    map.setCenter(markerClusterer.getCenter());
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
});
```

ie. I set zoomOnClick=false to have finer control of the map zooming behaviour to control the zoom amount and zoom location each click triggers.

Comment: `zoomOnClick: false` Was the key

Comment: Setting zoomOnclick to false forces you to have to double click, which sux. The maxZoom only seems to apply to double clicking clusters.

Comment: I get the error markerClusterer.getCenter is not a function.

Comment: @LauraNMS it should be ```cluster.getCenter()```

Answer (score 4):

It appears the API will only let you toggle the zoom functionality

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html

So you will have to edit the source, it appears to be on line 1055

```
/**
 * Triggers the clusterclick event and zoom's if the option is set.
 */
ClusterIcon.prototype.triggerClusterClick = function() {
  var markerClusterer = this.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer();

  // Trigger the clusterclick event.
  google.maps.event.trigger(markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', this.cluster_);

  if (markerClusterer.isZoomOnClick()) {
    // Zoom into the cluster.
    this.map_.fitBounds(this.cluster_.getBounds());
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs to write this function in coffeescript I merged the top answer and the marked answer into one code snippet.

```
mcOptions =
  maxZoom: 16

markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer map, markers, mcOptions
# listener if a cluster is clicked
google.maps.event.addListener markerCluster, "clusterclick", (cluster) ->
  if markerCluster.isZoomOnClick() # default is true
    #get bounds of cluster
    map.fitBounds cluster.getBounds()
    #zoom in to max zoom plus one. 
    map.setZoom markerCluster.getMaxZoom() + 1
```

This code check is zoom on click is set. If it is zoom in to max zoom plus one, and center on the cluster. Very simple code.