# GeoJSON, Overlapping Pointers, OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm fairly new to the Google Maps Api. In GeoJson file I have list of geo locations (cordinates lat-lon).

with:

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('json/geojson.json');
```

I'm putting data on map as Point-s. I have problem with Points that have same cordinates.

I found this
https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

but this works with markers so i cant get it to work.

Suggestions? Can I do it with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier?

My code:

```
function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: {lat: 45.8167, lng: 15.9833}
    });

    map.data.loadGeoJson('json/geojson.json');

    //////////////////////////
    //CODE FOR GROUPING POINTERS/MARKERS
    //////////////////////////

    map.data.setStyle(function (feature) {
        return {
            icon: '/inc/mapper/img/' + feature.getProperty('icon_url') + '.png',
        };
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You can do it with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.  Not sure what the performance would be like.  Do you have an example of the geojson (an example code snippet or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would also be helpful)

Comment: [question on SO regarding using the MarkerClusterer with GeoJSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267146/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-data-layer-markerclusterer/25274106#25274106)

Comment: [question on SO regarding using the MarkerClusterer with the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925546/error-when-restricting-zoom-levels-using-markerclusterer-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the GeoJson, create your own markers, add them to the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.

Examples below use MarkerClustererPlus and OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier, data from GeoJSON local to the page.

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gL3L7zso/176/) (duplicate marker position at Bielefeld in the center)

Working code snippet:

```js
var map = null;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var boxText = document.createElement("div");
boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
var infobox = new InfoBox({
  content: boxText,
  disableAutoPan: false,
  maxWidth: 0,
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
  zIndex: null,
  boxStyle: {
    background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
    opacity: 0.75,
    width: "280px"
  },
  closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
  closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
  infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
  isHidden: false,
  pane: "floatPane",
  enableEventPropagation: false
});

var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(null, null, {
  imagePath: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/images/m"
});
minClusterZoom = 14;
markerClusterer.setMaxZoom(minClusterZoom);

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52, 8),
    zoom: 4
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {
    markersWontMove: true,
    markersWontHide: true,
    keepSpiderfied: true
  });

  markerClusterer.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map.data, 'addfeature', function(e) {
    if (e.feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: e.feature.getGeometry().get(),
        title: e.feature.getProperty('name'),
        map: map
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(marker, e) {
        return function() {

          var myHTML = e.feature.getProperty('name');
          boxText.innerHTML = "<div style='text-align: center;'><b>" + myHTML + "</b></div>";
          infobox.setPosition(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
          infobox.setOptions({
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)
          });
          infobox.open(map);
        };
      }(marker, e));
      markerClusterer.addMarker(marker);
      oms.addMarker(marker);

      bounds.extend(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      map.setCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
    }
  });
  layer = map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  map.data.setMap(null);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
    infobox.close();
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var geoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Bielefeld"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [8.528849, 52.030656]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Bielefeld2"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [8.528849, 52.030656]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Herford"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [8.676780, 52.118003]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Guetersloh"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [8.383353, 51.902917]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Guetersloh2"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [8.38, 51.9]
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/v3-utility-library@master/archive/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: For anyone that is looking to do this without using `google.maps.Marker` instances, I've created a library based on the original OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier library here: https://github.com/slovely/OverlappingFeatureSpiderfier/

Comment: @Simon is there any demo ?

Comment: @Hassan sorry, no I don't have a demo of this anywhere.  It works almost the same as the original spidifier library.  Feel free to open a github issue if you have specific questions though!